# Display last page of paginated results instead of 404 using ListView

Tags: django, django-views

The Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view) show how to return the last page of a paginated queryset using a function-based view by catching the `EmptyPage` exception.

What's the easiest way to achieve the same thing using generic class-based views, for example `ListView`?

I first thought that the [`allow_empty`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.allow_empty) setting for `MultipleObjectMixin` would do what I need, but examining the code shows that it only prevents a 404 error if there are zero objects in the queryset, rather than zero objects on the page requested.

Two options seem to be:

1. subclass `ListView` and override `paginate_queryset` (inherited from `MultipleObjectMixin`), or
2. subclass `Paginator` and override `validate_number`, and set `paginator_class` to the subclass in the view.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 9):

Here's what option 2 looks like:

```
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage, Paginator
from django.views.generic import ListView

class SafePaginator(Paginator):
    def validate_number(self, number):
        try:
            return super(SafePaginator, self).validate_number(number)
        except EmptyPage:
            if number > 1:
                return self.num_pages
            else:
                raise

class MyView(ListView):
    paginator_class = SafePaginator
    paginate_by = 25

    [...]
```

This seems like the best option to me at the moment.

Comment: FYI, this does not update the page query parameter to the correct number.

Answer (score 1):

I simplified TimB answer:

```py
class SafePaginator(Paginator):
    def validate_number(self, number):
        try:
            number = int(number)
        except ValueError:
            number = 1
        return min(number, self.num_pages)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very old i know, but i needed it and i went for the first option
Here is how 1st option looks like:

```
class MyView(ListView):
    .....
    .....
    def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, page_size):
        """Paginate the queryset, if needed."""
        paginator = self.get_paginator(
            queryset, page_size, orphans=self.get_paginate_orphans(),
            allow_empty_first_page=self.get_allow_empty())
        page_kwarg = self.page_kwarg
        page = self.kwargs.get(page_kwarg) or self.request.GET.get(page_kwarg) or 1
        try:
            page_number = int(page)
        except ValueError:
            if page == 'last':
                page_number = paginator.num_pages
            else:
                # This was modified to prevent value error related stuff
                page_number = 1
        try:
            page = paginator.page(page_number)
            return paginator, page, page.object_list, page.has_other_pages()
        except InvalidPage as e:
            # this is where you should do the invalid Page error handling
            if page_number < 1:
                page_number = 1
            else:
                page_number = paginator.num_pages
            page = paginator.page(page_number)
            return paginator, page, page.object_list, page.has_other_pages()
```

TBH this seems very verbose, if there is a better option i ll vouch for it

Answer (score 0):

If you use TimB's answer, and you need or want to redirect to the last valid page, here is one way of doing that:

implement a get (or post) method in the relevant view if you haven't already.
Here is mine (with placeholder variable names):

```
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        result = super(YourClassHere, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
        # get the current page number if present
        page = int(self.request.GET.get("page")) if self.request.GET.get("page") else 1

        # get the maximum page number
        total_page = result.context_data['context_item_that_conatins_the_paginator'][0].num_pages

        if page > total_page:
            # make an http response
            response = redirect(reverse('namespace:pageName'))

            # set the page
            response['Location'] += f'?page={total_page}'

            # Maintain get variables if present 
            for var_title, var_data in self.request.GET.items():
                if var_title != "page":
                    response['Location'] += f"&{var_title}={var_data}"

            return response
        return result
```

in order to define the 'context_item_that_conatins_the_paginator' you will probably need to implement `get_context_data` as well if you haven't already

also, depending on your implementation your paginator may be in an entirely different part of your `context_data` - and you might have to use a debugger or other methods to see what's in it in order to find the `num_pages` variable

note: this method was done with Django 4.0