# Django : Paginator page exceed max page

Tags: django

I'm currently working on CBV Paginator in Django redirecting last page when given page exceed maximum pages. So, let's say there's Post models that has 200 instances and ListView with paginated_by=10. Then maximum page is 20.

So, when I enter URL with "?page=21", it return 404 Error Page. I want to redirect to maximum page.

How can I do?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: are you using drf for pagination or django based pagination?

Comment: I'm using django based pagination using django.views.generic.ListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at `django.views.generic.list`[link](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/views/generic/list.py) you have the following `ListView` class:

```
class ListView(MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin, BaseListView):
    """
    Render some list of objects, set by `self.model` or `self.queryset`.
    `self.queryset` can actually be any iterable of items, not just a queryset.
    """
```

which include `BaseListView` for pagination which inherit from `MultipleObjectMixin`:

```
class MultipleObjectMixin(ContextMixin):
    """A mixin for views manipulating multiple objects."""
    ... #other functions
    def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, page_size):
    """Paginate the queryset, if needed."""
    paginator = self.get_paginator(
        queryset, page_size, orphans=self.get_paginate_orphans(),
        allow_empty_first_page=self.get_allow_empty())
    page_kwarg = self.page_kwarg
    page = self.kwargs.get(page_kwarg) or self.request.GET.get(page_kwarg) or 1
    try:
        page_number = int(page)
    except ValueError:
        if page == 'last':
            page_number = paginator.num_pages
        else:
            raise Http404(_("Page is not 'last', nor can it be converted to an int."))
    try:
        page = paginator.page(page_number)
        return (paginator, page, page.object_list, page.has_other_pages())
    except InvalidPage as e:
        raise Http404(_('Invalid page (%(page_number)s): %(message)s') % {
            'page_number': page_number,
            'message': str(e)
        }) #<- the 404 page you want to redirect
```

You need to override the `InvalidPage` exception handling which raise the `Http404`:

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class YourListView(ListView):

    def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, page_size):
       """Paginate the queryset, if needed."""
       paginator = self.get_paginator(
       queryset, page_size, orphans=self.get_paginate_orphans(),
                allow_empty_first_page=self.get_allow_empty())
       page_kwarg = self.page_kwarg
       page = self.kwargs.get(page_kwarg) or self.request.GET.get(page_kwarg) or 1
       try:
           page_number = int(page)
       except ValueError:
           if page == 'last':
              page_number = paginator.num_pages
           else:
              raise Http404(_("Page is not 'last', nor can it be converted to an int."))
       try:
           page = paginator.page(page_number)
           return (paginator, page, page.object_list, page.has_other_pages())
       except InvalidPage as e:
           page_number = paginator.num_pages #<-last page
           page = paginator.page(page_number)
           return (paginator, page, page.object_list, page.has_other_pages()) #<-return last page
```

Note: you can also use this custom class for other ListView

Comment: Thanks for your work. I wonder if there is other way like redirecting. Following your code, url still show wrong page.

Comment: i don't think there is, because you using pre built CBV that had the pagination logic built in already, to change the ListView class behavior(if the docs doesn't mention/support it) you have to override it

Comment: @jake_kil is the exceed max page range still return 404?

Comment: Nope. it returns maximum page and works well. I just wondered if there is other way like redirecting. BTW, Thank you!

Comment: np, glad it helped you!

Comment: @jake_kil after looking around there a shorter way following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40835335/11225821.This doesn't do the redirect either but it can be shorter than mine current one. I prefer my method because it's better to reuse custom class than override a method each time you call ListView

Comment: I agree with you. that can be more simple, but your one is much better to reuse!. Thanks a lot!